# How does Bit wise operators work with Enums

Tags: c#, .net, enums

```
enum WeekDays
{
    Monday = 0,
    Tuesday = 1,
    Wednesday = 2,
    Thursday = 3,
    Friday = 4,
    Saturday = 5,
    Sunday = 6
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WeekDays days0 = WeekDays.Monday | WeekDays.Tuesday | WeekDays.Wednesday;

    WeekDays days1 = WeekDays.Monday | WeekDays.Tuesday | WeekDays.Wednesday | WeekDays.Thursday;

    WeekDays days2 = WeekDays.Monday | WeekDays.Tuesday | WeekDays.Wednesday | WeekDays.Thursday | WeekDays.Friday;
}
```

Output is:

```
days0 = Thursday,
days1 = Thursday,
days2 = 7
```

Can anybody explain the logic how this works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, your enum isn't suitable for use with bitwise operations. To be appropriate for bitwise operations, each distinct value should be represented by a different bit - whereas you've just got the numbers 0-6.

The reason you're getting the output you have is that:

- `days0` is `0 | 1 | 2`, which is 3, the value of `Thursday`
- `days1` is `0 | 1 | 2 | 3` which is still 3, the value of `Thursday`
- `days2` is `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4` which is 7, which isn't a named value in your enum

To make your enum work appropriate for bitwise operations, you should declare it like this:

```
[Flags] // Affects string parsing and formatting
enum BitwiseWeekDays
{
    None = 0,
    Monday = 1 << 0,
    Tuesday = 1 << 1,
    Wednesday = 1 << 2,
    Thursday = 1 << 3,
    Friday = 1 << 4,
    Saturday = 1 << 5,
    Sunday = 1 << 6
}
```

Now each value is represented by a separate bit, so you can "or" them together to combine them.

Answer (score 4):

```
0 | 1 | 2 = (bitwise  00 | 01 | 10 = 11 ) = 3
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 = (bitwise  00 | 01 | 10 | 11 = 11 ) = 3
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 = (bitwise  000 | 001 | 010 | 011 | 100 = 111 ) = 7
```